# Determining the pattern orientation of a spatiotemporal image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

How can I obtain average direction of the pattern shown in the figure below. It is the direction of the red arrow relative to the yellow (horizontal) line. Any ideas for an approach? I couldn't figure out a way to approach. This is a spatio-temporal image created from a video. Thank you.

[image: Figure A]

Here is my original image:[image]

Comment: any own ideas??

Comment: @Piglet Small idea. Detection of edges and then orientation is perpendicular to the gradient of the edge?

Comment: Down-votes please with comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to compute the gradient vector (x derivative and y derivative) and find its direction at each pixel (`atan2(y,x)`). The average orientation is what you want, not the average direction (will cancel out). So apply modulus pi, then average across the image.

The best way to compute image gradients is through the [Gaussian gradients](http://www.crisluengo.net/index.php/archives/22).

The [structure tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_tensor) is the more robust way of accomplishing this. In short, it computes local averages of the gradient vector to reduce the effect of noise. It does this by computing the outer product of the gradient vector with itself, which produces a symmetric matrix. The individual components of this matrix can then be locally averaged (i.e. apply a smoothing filter). This is similar to computing the angle of the vectors, doubling the angles to make vectors in opposite directions equal, then averaging them.

Note that you can apply either of these solutions in 3D (you can think of the video data as 2D + time = 3D). That way, you compute both the speed and the direction of motion within the 2D frame, rather than just the speed along the direction in which you extracted the 2D image you show in the question. The image gradient and the concept of the structure tensor easily extend to 3D. This 3D approach is similar to the approach by [Lucas-Kanade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Kanade_method) for optical flow. If you follow that link to Wikipedia, you'll see it uses the structure tensor in 2D, and adds gradients along the time dimension.

Comment: I used structure tensors. It works. But hard to define certain sigma value. Thank you.

Comment: Note that you can do the same operation in 3D (x,y,t) across all your video data in one go. You can then determine velocity in 2D, not only parallel to the direction in which you've extracted the 2D image you're showing here. That solution then corresponds roughly to Lukas-Kanade optical flow (their solution includes an optimization step to fill in velocity vectors in featureless areas, and prevents velocities to only be accurate near edges).

Comment: Thank you. I have created another question before in another community "DSP" (https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/42971/determining-the-pattern-direction-of-a-bitmap-image). I added my approach there. Could you please look that answer also, and considering simultaneous operation in 3D space as mentioned by you before, edit your answer with more details. Then others who looking for this question will get understood. Thank you.

Comment: OK, I've added these comments to the answer. I hope they are useful to some.

Answer (score 2):

Might be useful to try Fourier transform.
In your case you should get two vertical lines in the middle of the transformed image corresponding to the information when traveling vertically in the image.
On the other hand there shouldn't be a horizontal line since when traveling horizontally in the image there is little information (little change)

For example you can use this online site to play with fourier transforms:
https://www.ejectamenta.com/Fourifier-fullscreen/

It might sound like the problem remains the same but in fact it is much easier now.
The 2D pattern is converted into dominant lines which are quite easy to find in the transformed image.
For example you can search for the strongest pixels in the image and simply determine if they are more likely to be horizontal line or a vertical line or determine the angle of the dominant line. Then rotate by 90 degrees.

For example see this image of wood grain and the resulting transformed image:
[image: Horizontal Wood grain]

[image: Transformed image]

And don't worry about the two lines. The image is symmetric so just ignore 3/4 of the image and look in 1 quarter.

Comment: Actually, half the FFT is unique if the transformed image is real. Not one quarter. You can ignore half the image, either vertically or horizontally, and look for peaks or lines there.

Comment: If you can ignore half the image, either vertically or horizontally, why not ignore both? Then you can ignore 3/4 of the image.

Comment: Because there are two unique quarters. The top left and bottom right quarters are mirrored copies of each other, as are the top right and bottom left. If you ignore half the image (any half, no matter how you cut it as long as it's a straight line through the middle point) then you have all unique information. The lines in the OP should form a straight line through the origin of the FT. If you ignore 3/4 of the image, you might pick a quarter that shows no line!

Comment: A different way of looking at it: The input image has N real values, its DFT has N complex values. If you separate the real and imaginary components, you are left with 2N values. Logically half of those must be redundant. In one quarter of the FT you have only N/2 values. If those represented all the information in the input image, than you have discovered the perfect image compression algorithm! Let's DFT that quarter again, reduces the data by half again, ...

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend giving the Hough transform a go, it is available in OpenCv. The Hough transform maps lines to angles, and might be useful in your case.